# Appending column totals to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with numerical values. What is the simplest way of appending a row (with a given index value) that represents the sum of each column?

Answer (score 109):

To add a `Total` column which is the sum across the row:

```
df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Does not give a meaningful result, if there are non-numeric columns in the df.

Comment: This answer adds a column, not a row as the asker requested.  (However, this answer helps me with the problem I was trying to solve, so I appreciate it.)

Comment: This answer is solving a different problem.

Answer (score 104):

To add a row with column-totals:

```
df.loc['Total']= df.sum()
```

Comment: Does not give a meaningful result, if there are non-numeric columns in the df.

Comment: Incase of nan, first apply df.fillna(0) then use this sum

Answer (score 54):

### ** Get Both Column Total and Row Total **

This gives total on both rows and columns:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10,20],'b':[100,200],'c': ['a','b']})

df.loc['Column_Total']= df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
df.loc[:,'Row_Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)

print(df)

                 a      b    c  Row_Total
0             10.0  100.0    a      110.0
1             20.0  200.0    b      220.0
Column_Total  30.0  300.0  NaN      330.0
```

Comment: solved it for me.  Is there  a YouTube video I can watch that explains how this works. Just reading the documentation is not the best when you're a visual learner like me.

Comment: This worked for me, but only after deleting `.loc`. Not sure why.

Answer (score 8):

One way is to create a DataFrame with the column sums, and use DataFrame.append(...). For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# Create some sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.randn(5), "B": np.random.randn(5)}) 
# Sum the columns:
sum_row = {col: df[col].sum() for col in df}
# Turn the sums into a DataFrame with one row with an index of 'Total':
sum_df = pd.DataFrame(sum_row, index=["Total"])
# Now append the row:
df = df.append(sum_df)
```

Answer (score 5):

I have done it this way:

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(df.sum(axis=0),columns=['Grand Total']).T])
```

this will add a column of totals for each row:

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(df.sum(axis=1),columns=['Total'])],axis=1)
```

It seems a little annoying to have to turn the `Series` object (or in the answer above, `dict`) back into a DataFrame and then append it, but it does work for my purpose.

It seems like this should just be a method of the `DataFrame` - like pivot_table has margins.

Perhaps someone knows of an easier way.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `append` method to add a series with the same index as the dataframe to the dataframe. For example:

```
df.append(pd.Series(df.sum(),name='Total'))
```

Comment: @Alexander Huszagh, what about both row and col total?

Comment: If you want to add to the end of your method chain do this: `.pipe(lambda df: df.append(pd.Series(df.sum(), name='Total')))`

Answer (score 1):

1. Calculate sum and convert result into list(axis=1:row wise sum, axis=0:column wise sum)
2. Add result of step-1, to the existing dataFrame with new name

```
new_sum_col = list(df.sum(axis=1))
df['new_col_name'] = new_sum_col
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the modern pandas approach! This solution is a bit dirty due to two chained transposition, I do not know how to use `.assign` on rows.

```py
# Generate DataFrame
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10,20],'b':[100,200],'c': ['a','b']})

# Solution
df.T.assign(Total = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)).T
```

output:

```py
    a    b  c  Total
0  10  100  a    110
1  20  200  b    220
```

Answer (score 0):

For those that have trouble because the result is `0` or `NaN`, check `dtype` first.

```py
df.dtypes
```

Since sum can only process numeric try to change the type of your dataframe first. In this example, chang to `int32` for integer.

```py
df = df.astype('int32')
df.dtypes
```

Then, you should be able to sum across row and add new column (as the accepted answer, not the question).

```py
df['sum']= df.sum(numeric_only=True,axis=1)
```

---

Bonus: Sort the sum column

```
df.sort_values(by=['sum'])
```