# Pandas dataframe total row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, something like:

```
     foo  bar  qux
0    a    1    3.14
1    b    3    2.72
2    c    2    1.62
3    d    9    1.41
4    e    3    0.58
```

and I would like to add a 'total' row to the end of dataframe:

```
     foo  bar  qux
0    a    1    3.14
1    b    3    2.72
2    c    2    1.62
3    d    9    1.41
4    e    3    0.58
5  total  18   9.47
```

I've tried to use the `sum` command but I end up with a Series, which although I can convert back to a Dataframe, doesn't maintain the data types:

```
tot_row = pd.DataFrame(df.sum()).T
tot_row['foo'] = 'tot'
tot_row.dtypes:
     foo    object
     bar    object
     qux    object
```

I would like to maintain the data types from the original data frame as I need to apply other operations to the total row, something like:

```
baz = 2*tot_row['qux'] + 3*tot_row['bar']
```

Comment: Try `df.loc['Total']= df.sum()`, referenced from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804673/appending-column-totals-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: update September 2022: there is a new pandas function that might help (`.style.concat()`). see my full answer below.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

### Update June 2022

`pd.append` is [now deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append). You could use `pd.concat` instead but it's probably easier to use `df.loc['Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True)`, as Kevin Zhu commented. Or, better still, don't modify the data frame in place and keep your data separate from your summary statistics!

---

Append a totals row with

```
df.append(df.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
```

The conversion is necessary only if you have a column of strings or objects.

It's a bit of a fragile solution so I'd recommend sticking to operations on the dataframe, though. eg.

```
baz = 2*df['qux'].sum() + 3*df['bar'].sum()
```

Comment: This doesn't maintain the original data types; all columns are converted to objects (strings by the looks of it).

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't check it with a column of strings. Updated now.

Comment: This is almost correct. The only thing is that the data types aren't quite preserved; ints are converted to floats. Luckily I don't think this will be an issue for me. I'll accept this solution if nobody posts an alternative today.

Comment: Updated again to prevent any type changes of summed numeric data. Strings will now shows up as `np.nan` in total row.

Comment: This is great. Worked for me, thanks. But how can I change the index back to my designated list after this?

Comment: Use `df.append(df.sum(numeric_only=True).rename('Total'))` if you want to preserve the index.

Comment: But won't this change the actual data of the DataFrame? So e.g. `df.describe()` would take the data plus the sum of the data?

Comment: append will be deprecated, use concat instead

Comment: June 2022: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.

Answer (score 76):

```
df.loc["Total"] = df.sum()
```

works for me and I find it easier to remember. Am I missing something?
Probably wasn't possible in earlier versions.

I'd actually like to add the total row only temporarily though.
Adding it permanently is good for display but makes it a hassle in further calculations.

Just found

```
df.append(df.sum().rename('Total'))
```

This prints what I want in a Jupyter notebook and appears to leave the df itself untouched.

Comment: June 2022: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.

Answer (score 63):

## New Method

To get both row and column total:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10,20],'b':[100,200],'c': ['a','b']})

df.loc['Column_Total']= df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
df.loc[:,'Row_Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)

print(df)


                 a      b    c  Row_Total
0             10.0  100.0    a      110.0
1             20.0  200.0    b      220.0
Column_Total  30.0  300.0  NaN      330.0
```

Answer (score 25):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) with `margins=True`:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [('a',1,3.14),('b',3,2.72),('c',2,1.62),('d',9,1.41),('e',3,.58)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('foo', 'bar', 'qux'))
```

Original `df`:

```
  foo  bar   qux
0   a    1  3.14
1   b    3  2.72
2   c    2  1.62
3   d    9  1.41
4   e    3  0.58
```

Since `pivot_table` requires some sort of grouping (without the `index` argument, it'll raise a `ValueError: No group keys passed!`), and your original index is vacuous, we'll use the `foo` column:

```
df.pivot_table(index='foo',
               margins=True,
               margins_name='total',  # defaults to 'All'
               aggfunc=sum)
```

*Voilà!*

```
       bar   qux
foo             
a        1  3.14
b        3  2.72
c        2  1.62
d        9  1.41
e        3  0.58
total   18  9.47
```

Comment: How can I ilmit the sum to only specific columns ?

Comment: This worked for me, but when I write df again in command prompt, it prints the old df and I do not see the sum. also it does not write the total in Excel file

Answer (score 10):

Alternative way (verified on Pandas 0.18.1):

```
import numpy as np
total = df.apply(np.sum)
total['foo'] = 'tot'
df.append(pd.DataFrame(total.values, index=total.keys()).T, ignore_index=True)
```

Result:

```
   foo   bar   qux
0    a     1  3.14
1    b     3  2.72
2    c     2  1.62
3    d     9  1.41
4    e     3  0.58
5  tot    18  9.47
```

Answer (score 10):

## New method [September 2022]

### TL;DR:

Just use

```
df.style.concat(df.agg(['sum']).style)
```

for a solution that won't change your dataframe, works even if you have an "sum" in your index, and can be styled!

### Explanation

In pandas 1.5.0, a new method named [`.style.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.concat.html) gives you the ability to display several dataframes together. This is a good way to show the total (or any other statistics), because it is not changing the original dataframe, and works even if you have an index named "sum" in your original dataframe.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df.style.concat(df.agg(['sum']).style)
```

and it will return a formatted table that is visible in jupyter as this:

[image: dataframe with a total row]

#### Styling

with a little longer code, you can even make the last row look different:

```py
df.style.concat(
    df.agg(['sum']).style
    .set_properties(**{'background-color': 'yellow'})
)
```

to get:

[image: dataframe with a yellow total row]

see other ways to style (such as bold font, or table lines) in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.concat.html)

Comment: I copied your example and did no edits, but got an error: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'concat'. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe you got an older version of pandas? concat was added in 1.5.0

Comment: @tsvikas You're correct. I had the same error but it worked after upgrading Pandas. Thanks

Comment: Please emphasize in the TL;DR section that your code only works in jupyter notebooks. This would add more clarity to this answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is the way that I do it, by transposing and using the assign method in combination with a lambda function. It makes it simple for me.

```
df.T.assign(GrandTotal = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)).T
```

Answer (score 6):

Building on JMZ answer

```
df.append(df.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
```

if you want to continue using your current index you can name the sum series using .rename() as follows:

```
df.append(df.sum().rename('Total'))
```

This will add a row at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 5):

Building on answer from Matthias Kauer.

To add row total:

```
df.loc["Row_Total"] = df.sum()
```

To add column total,

```
df.loc[:,"Column_Total"] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Following helped for me to add a column total and row total to a dataframe.

Assume dft1 is your original dataframe... now add a column total and row total with the following steps.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

#create dataframe string
dfstr = StringIO(u"""
a;b;c
1;1;1
2;2;2
3;3;3
4;4;4
5;5;5
""")

#create dataframe dft1 from string
dft1 = pd.read_csv(dfstr, sep=";")

## add a column total to dft1
dft1['Total'] = dft1.sum(axis=1)

## add a row total to dft1 with the following steps

sum_row = dft1.sum(axis=0) #get sum_row first
dft1_sum=pd.DataFrame(data=sum_row).T #change it to a dataframe

dft1_sum=dft1_sum.reindex(columns=dft1.columns) #line up the col index to dft1
dft1_sum.index = ['row_total'] #change row index to row_total

dft1.append(dft1_sum) # append the row to dft1
```

Comment: [`df.append` is deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#whatsnew-140-deprecations-frame-series-append)

Answer (score 0):

Actually all proposed solutions render the original DataFrame unusable for any further analysis and can invalidate following computations, which will be **easy to overlook** and could **lead to false results**.

This is because you add a row to the data, which Pandas cannot differentiate from an additional row of data.

**Example:**

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [1, 5, 6, 8, 9]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
df.describe()
```

yields

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 9 |

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| count | 5 |
| mean | 5.8 |
| std | 3.11448 |
| min | 1 |
| 25% | 5 |
| 50% | 6 |
| 75% | 8 |
| max | 9 |

After

```py
df.loc['Totals']= df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
```

the dataframe looks like this

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 9 |
| Totals | 29 |

This looks nice, **but the new row is treated as if it was an additional data item**, so `df.describe` will produce false results:

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| count | 6 |
| mean | 9.66667 |
| std | 9.87252 |
| min | 1 |
| 25% | 5.25 |
| 50% | 7 |
| 75% | 8.75 |
| max | 29 |

So: **Watch out!** and **apply this only after doing all other analyses of the data or work on a copy of the DataFrame!**

Answer (score 0):

When the "totals" need to be added to an index column:

```py
totals = pd.DataFrame(df.sum(numeric_only=True)).transpose().set_index(pd.Index({"totals"}))
df.append(totals)
```

e.g.

```py
(Pdb) df
        count    min bytes    max bytes    mean bytes     std bytes     sum bytes
row_0  837200      67412.0  368733992.0  2.518989e+07  5.122836e+07  2.108898e+13
row_1  299000      85380.0  692782132.0  2.845055e+08  2.026823e+08  8.506713e+13
row_2  837200      67412.0  379484173.0  8.706825e+07  1.071484e+08  7.289354e+13
row_3  239200      85392.0  328063972.0  9.870446e+07  1.016989e+08  2.361011e+13
row_4   59800      67292.0  383487021.0  1.841879e+08  1.567605e+08  1.101444e+13
row_5  717600     112309.0  379483824.0  9.687554e+07  1.103574e+08  6.951789e+13
row_6  119600     664144.0  358486985.0  1.611637e+08  1.171889e+08  1.927518e+13
row_7  478400      67300.0  593141462.0  2.824301e+08  1.446283e+08  1.351146e+14
row_8  358800  215002028.0  327493141.0  2.861329e+08  1.545693e+07  1.026645e+14
row_9  358800  202248016.0  321657935.0  2.684668e+08  1.865470e+07  9.632590e+13

(Pdb) totals = pd.DataFrame(df.sum(numeric_only=True)).transpose()
(Pdb) totals
       count    min bytes     max bytes    mean bytes     std bytes     sum bytes
0  4305600.0  418466685.0  4.132815e+09  1.774725e+09  1.025805e+09  6.365722e+14

(Pdb) totals = pd.DataFrame(df.sum(numeric_only=True)).transpose().set_index(pd.Index({"totals"}))
(Pdb) totals
            count    min bytes     max bytes    mean bytes     std bytes     sum bytes
totals  4305600.0  418466685.0  4.132815e+09  1.774725e+09  1.025805e+09  6.365722e+14

(Pdb) df.append(totals)
            count    min bytes     max bytes    mean bytes     std bytes     sum bytes
row_0    837200.0      67412.0  3.687340e+08  2.518989e+07  5.122836e+07  2.108898e+13
row_1    299000.0      85380.0  6.927821e+08  2.845055e+08  2.026823e+08  8.506713e+13
row_2    837200.0      67412.0  3.794842e+08  8.706825e+07  1.071484e+08  7.289354e+13
row_3    239200.0      85392.0  3.280640e+08  9.870446e+07  1.016989e+08  2.361011e+13
row_4     59800.0      67292.0  3.834870e+08  1.841879e+08  1.567605e+08  1.101444e+13
row_5    717600.0     112309.0  3.794838e+08  9.687554e+07  1.103574e+08  6.951789e+13
row_6    119600.0     664144.0  3.584870e+08  1.611637e+08  1.171889e+08  1.927518e+13
row_7    478400.0      67300.0  5.931415e+08  2.824301e+08  1.446283e+08  1.351146e+14
row_8    358800.0  215002028.0  3.274931e+08  2.861329e+08  1.545693e+07  1.026645e+14
row_9    358800.0  202248016.0  3.216579e+08  2.684668e+08  1.865470e+07  9.632590e+13
totals  4305600.0  418466685.0  4.132815e+09  1.774725e+09  1.025805e+09  6.365722e+14
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i generally want to do this at the very end as to avoid breaking the integrity of the dataframe (right before printing). I created a summary_rows_cols method which returns a printable dataframe:

```
def summary_rows_cols(df: pd.DataFrame,
                      column_sum: bool = False,
                      column_avg: bool = False,
                      column_median: bool = False,
                      row_sum: bool = False,
                      row_avg: bool = False,
                      row_median: bool = False
                      ) -> pd.DataFrame:
    ret = df.copy()

    if column_sum: ret.loc['Sum'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
    if column_avg: ret.loc['Avg'] = df.mean(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
    if column_median: ret.loc['Median'] = df.median(numeric_only=True, axis=0)
    if row_sum: ret.loc[:, 'Sum'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
    if row_median: ret.loc[:, 'Avg'] = df.mean(numeric_only=True, axis=1)
    if row_avg: ret.loc[:, 'Median'] = df.median(numeric_only=True, axis=1)

    ret.fillna('-', inplace=True)

    return ret
```

This allows me to enter a generic (numeric) df and get a summarized output such as:

```
     a   b   c Sum Median
0    1   4   7  12      4
1    2   5   8  15      5
2    3   6   9  18      6
Sum  6  15  24   -      -
```

from:

```
data = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [4, 5, 6],
    'c': [7, 8, 9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

printable = summary_rows_cols(df, row_sum=True, column_sum=True, row_median=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.agg(["sum"])])
```

The advantage of this is that it can also be used in a method chain, like so:

```
df = (pd._testing.makeDataFrame()
      .set_index("A")  # Do some stuff (e.g., in this and the next line).
      .reset_index()
      .pipe(lambda df_: pd.concat([df_, df_.agg(["sum"])]))  # Add the sum row.
      )
```

Another benefit is that the index (or index label) of the newly created row is automatically given the name `sum`.