# Adding row of totals in pandas dataframe without the sum of names?

Tags: python, pandas, rows

I have this dataframe:

```
Data = {'name':  ['a', 'b'],
        'number1': [5, 3],
        'number2': [3, 2]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns = ['name','number1', 'number2'])
```

I want to add another row which would contain sums of columns `number1` and `number2`. So my desired result is this:

```
Data2 = {'name':  ['a', 'b', 'total'],
        'number1': [5, 3, 8],
        'number2': [3, 2, 5]
        }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Data2, columns = ['name','number1', 'number2'])
```

I tried the solution offered in this thread:
[Pandas dataframe total row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752399/pandas-dataframe-total-row)

But this line

```
df.loc["Total"] = df.sum()
```

also makes a sum of names so in the end I get `Total` as my index and in names column I get a value `ab` (because a+b). Is there a way to get a `df` that looks exactly the same as my desired result `df`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
m=df.set_index('name')
m.loc['total']=m.sum()
print(m)
```

---

```
       number1  number2
name                   
a            5        3
b            3        2
total        8        5
```

You can also `reset_index()` if you intend to have the `name` column as column:

```
print(m.reset_index())
```

---

```
    name  number1  number2
0      a        5        3
1      b        3        2
2  total        8        5
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using `.loc`

```
df.loc[df.index.max()+1]=['total']+df.sum().tolist()[1:]
df
Out[80]: 
    name  number1  number2
0      a        5        3
1      b        3        2
2  total        8        5
```

Comment: After 4 hours of trying every other solution under the son, this is the only thing that worked for me in a jupyter notebook.  This is insane.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) by columns filtered by positions by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or only numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
df.loc[len(df)] = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum().append(pd.Series({'name':'total'}))
print (df)
    name  number1  number2
0      a        5        3
1      b        3        2
2  total        8        5
```

Or:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = df.select_dtypes(np.number).sum().append(pd.Series({'name':'total'}))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
df.append(df.sum().rename('total').replace({'ab':'total'})).reset_index(drop=True)

     name  number1  number2
0      a        5        3
1      b        3        2
2  total        8        5
```