# How to append a "Total" row to pandas dataframe with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose you have a simple pandas dataframe with a MultiIndex:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(1, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('one', 'elem1'), ('one', 'elem2'), ('two', 'elem1'), ('two', 'elem2')]),
                  columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Printed as a table:

```
           col1  col2
one elem1     1     1
    elem2     1     1
two elem1     1     1
    elem2     1     1
```

**Question**: How do you add a "Total" row to that Dataframe?

Expected output:

```
             col1  col2
one   elem1   1.0   1.0
      elem2   1.0   1.0
two   elem1   1.0   1.0
      elem2   1.0   1.0
Total         4.0   4.0
```

---

### First attempt: Naive implementation

If I am just ignoring the MultiIndex and follow the [standard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752399/pandas-dataframe-total-row)

```
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()
```

Output:

```
              col1  col2
(one, elem1)     1     1
(one, elem2)     1     1
(two, elem1)     1     1
(two, elem2)     1     1
Total            4     4
```

It seems to be correct, but the MultiIndex is transformed to `Index([('one', 'elem1'), ('one', 'elem2'), ('two', 'elem1'), ('two', 'elem2'), 'Total'], dtype='object')`

---

### Second attempt: Be explicit

```py
df.loc['Total', :] = df.sum()
```

or (being frustrated and changing the axis just out of spite)

```py
df.loc['Total', :] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

Output (the same for both calls):

```
             col1  col2
one   elem1   1.0   1.0
      elem2   1.0   1.0
two   elem1   1.0   1.0
      elem2   1.0   1.0
Total         NaN   NaN
```

The MultiIndex is not transformed, but the Total is wrong (NaN != 4).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The solution

You have to remove the index of `df.sum()` and just use the values:

```py
df.loc['Total', :] = df.sum().values
```

Output:

```
             col1  col2
one   elem1   1.0   1.0
      elem2   1.0   1.0
two   elem1   1.0   1.0
      elem2   1.0   1.0
Total         4.0   4.0
```

---

### Why was the second attempt wrong?

The second attempt was almost correct. But df.sum() has the `Index(['col1', 'col2'], dtype='object')`. Consequently, pandas isn't able to match the index. The new index ('Total', '') is appended but without values.

But why did `df.loc['Total', :] = df.sum(axis=1)` also fail? It has the correct Multiindex. Pandas does exactly what you told it, i.e. sum the columns. So, `df.sum(axis=1)` gives you the following dataframe:

```
one  elem1    2
     elem2    2
two  elem1    2
     elem2    2
```

This dataframe can't be matched with the original `df` in any meaningful sense.

Comment: This solution has the same visual result for the values, but it bumps all the values in the dataframe to float (to start with they were int64). The `df.loc['Total'] = df.sum().values`  does not do this (it has the tupleized index problem instead..)

Answer (score 1):

Building on @above_c_level's accepted answer, here is a function:

- Handles multi-index
- Also preserves dtypes

```py
def with_totals(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
     '''Return new df with row & col totals named ∑. 
        * Preserves dtypes. 
        * Handles multi-index.
    '''
     df['∑'] = df.sum(axis=1)  # Row totals in new column
     D = df.dtypes
     df.loc['∑', :] = df.sum().values 
     return df.astype(D)
```

Usage:

```py
with_totals(df)
```

Output:

```
            col1 col2   ∑
one elem1      1    1   2
    elem2      1    1   2
two elem1      1    1   2
    elem2      1    1   2
∑              4    4   8
```

### Discussion

The key move remains the twin use of `.loc` and `.values`:

```py
df.loc['Total', :] = df.sum().values
```

But dtypes can [get lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752399/pandas-dataframe-total-row). In my case my ints were converted to objects, which rendered as floats, making it hard to read. The best answer I found was to remember and re-apply the dtypes.

---