# Pandas Append a Total Row with pandas.concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tried to find how to append a `Total Row`, which sums the columns.

There is a elegant solution to this problem here: [**[SOLVED] Pandas dataframe total row**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752399/pandas-dataframe-total-row)

However, when using this method, I have noticed a warning message:

```
FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
```

I have tried to use this alternative, in order to avoid using legacy code. When I tried to use `concat` method, it was appending the sum row to the last column vertically.

**Code I used**:

```py
pd.concat( [df, df.sum(numeric_only=True)] )
```

**Result**:

```
         a       b     c         d         e
0   2200.0   14.30   NaN   2185.70       NaN
1   3200.0   20.80   NaN   3179.20       NaN
2   6400.0   41.60   NaN   6358.40       NaN
3      NaN     NaN   NaN       NaN  11800.00     <-- Appended using Concat
4      NaN     NaN   NaN       NaN     76.70     <-- Appended using Concat
5      NaN     NaN   NaN       NaN      0.00     <-- Appended using Concat
6      NaN     NaN   NaN       NaN  11723.30     <-- Appended using Concat
```

**What I want**:

```
           a       b      c          d
0     2200.0   14.30    NaN    2185.70
1     3200.0   20.80    NaN    3179.20
2     6400.0   41.60    NaN    6358.40
3   11800.00   76.70   0.00   11723.30     <-- Appended using Concat
```

Is there an elegant solution to this problem using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method?

Comment: Try `df.loc['Total'] = df.sum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the sum (which is a `pandas.Series`) to a DataFrame and transpose before `concat`:

```
>>> pd.concat([df,df.sum().to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)

         a     b    c        d
0   2200.0  14.3  NaN   2185.7
1   3200.0  20.8  NaN   3179.2
2   6400.0  41.6  NaN   6358.4
3  11800.0  76.7  0.0  11723.3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I have tried to Google how to transpose the array, but didn't know you have to use `to_frame`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solutions, in pandas documentations, pd.concat([df1, df1]), doesn't work the same as df1.append(df2) would

Answer (score 0):

The elegant solution is

```
pd.concat([df, df.agg(["sum"])])
```

which is quite short. The `[]` around `"sum"` causes that `df.agg(["sum"])` returns a row (i.e. DataFrame). Without the `[]`, a Series would be returned (which would not be in the interest of this solution). The index label of the newly generated row is automatically given the name `sum`, see the output:

```
         a     b    c        d
0     2200  14.3  NaN   2185.7
1     3200  20.8  NaN   3179.2
2     6400  41.6  NaN   6358.4
sum  11800  76.7  0.0  11723.3
```