# How to create a new row with the total sum of a axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need create a new row with the total value of axis 0 sum.

I have the follow series values:

```
INDEX
0      -1.09
1       1.15
2      -0.28
3      -0.14
4       0.62
```

How can i add a new row at the end of series with the total sum, like this:

```
INDEX
0      -1.09
1       1.15
2      -0.28
3      -0.14
4       0.62
TOTAL   0.26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.set_value('TOTAL',df.sum())
```

Answer (score 3):

You should find your answer here :

[Appending column totals to a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804673/appending-column-totals-to-a-pandas-dataframe)

Precisely : df.loc['Total']= df.sum()