# Add row of column totals in polars

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

I'm trying to move away from pandas to polars, I have a use case where I need to add the column totals as a new row to the polars lazy frame.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804673/appending-column-totals-to-a-pandas-dataframe) and it would perfectly solve my problem in pandas, but I haven't found any way or documentation on how to translate this code to polars.

Comment: It helps answerers and future readers if you include a small input / output dataframe example in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a new row with the total of each column, you can first create a row of the column totals using an aggregation and then concatenate it to the dataframe using [`pl.concat`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html).

```py
pl.concat([df, df.select(pl.all().sum())])
```

#### Previous answer

*Disclaimer.* My original answer was based on the answer to the linked pandas question. It actually create a new *column* with the total of each *row*.

To create a new column *total* that is given by the horizontal sum of all other columns, use [`pl.sum_horizontal`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.sum_horizontal.html) as follows.

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all()).alias("total")
)
```

If you don't want to sum *all columns*, give the corresponding column names directly to `pl.sum_horizontal`, e.g. `pl.sum_horizontal("A", "B", "C")`.

Comment: I think you saw the wrong answer on the linked thread, I need to get the columns totals as a new row, not a horizontal sum of all columns.